# Tablesorter filter not applying

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

[Beta Site](http://beta.apogeerockets.com/index.php?main_page=product_rocket_info&cPath=1_2&products_id=6)

I've got a bootstrap site template that I'm using for a dynamic redesign of my work's website, and am trying to initialize the filter function on Mottie's Tablesorter fork (2.21.4), and jquery 1.11.1.

I've got the filter to show, it's responding to select/false/etc filters I give the headers, and I can input text or select a drop-down, but it's not actually filtering anything. Sort works fine. I'm still a jquery noob, so I'm wondering if there's a conflict somewhere.

We have an older version (2.10.8) working just fine on our [current site](https://www.apogeerockets.com/Rocket_Kits/Skill_Level_1_Kits/Apprentice_Rocket_Kit) using a dynamically generated table.  On the beta, the dynamic table wasn't sorting, so I copied the code directly from Mottie and it is still not working.  :/

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/861 post here what you did and I'll upvote it :D